# Area under the graph of a function defines Integration or Integration defines area under the graph of a function?

Tags: integration, area

What will be the area under the curve x^(-1/3) in the interval [-1, 1]?
Is this area finite?
Does definite integration in any interval always computes area under the curve of the function in that interval?